# How to store an OAuth token for a Camel route

Tags: oauth-2.0, apache-camel

I'm new to OAuth and fairly new to Camel. I have a Camel route using http4 component that will need to use an OAuth client credentials grant flow to access a b2b API.

There's currently no OAuth component for Camel so I guess I will have to implement something myself. As I understand is I will ask for a token to use for subsequent requests but is there any guidance for storing this token? Is it discouraged to store this in the http4 cookie store?

Comment: http://camel.apache.org/tutorial-oauth.html

Comment: page not found @Namphibian

Comment: It was just a comment not an answer. Pretty easy to get Oauth working with Camel if you are working with spring just use Spring's Oauth features.